# create_singlethread_workqueue in linux

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am very much new to the linux kernel development and getting confused in understanding the function `create_singlethread_workqueue()`. Can any one please provide with a basic example what exactly does `create_singlethread_workqueue()` do and what is the job of `INIT_WORK` .From the explanations I read it says it creates a queue for a processor and initializes work .
But not able to understand what work ,and not able to understand how can I understand with a basic example .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function `create_singlethread_workqueue()` will create a work queue. A work queue is just a queue to which you submit work. "work" here means any function that you would want to run at a given point in time. This work will be executed by a single worker thread which is also created when you call `create_singlethread_workqueue()`.

```c
struct workqueue_struct *create_singlethread_workqueue(const char *name);
```

Secondly, `INIT_WORK` is a mechanism to initialize the work struct at run time. There is a way to do the initialization at compile time too.

```c
INIT_WORK(struct work_struct *work, void (*function)(void *), void *data);
```

This means whenever we queue the `work_struct *work` on to a `workqueue`, the function pointed to by `(*function)` will be called with argument `void *data`.
Let's see how we queue work:

```c
int queue_work(struct workqueue_struct *queue, struct work_struct *work);
```

So here we have queued/submitted the work to a `workqueue *queue`. This will ultimately execute function pointed to by `(*function)` with argument `void *data` specified in the `INIT_WORK()`